# Using Google Docs API v1's insertInlineImage(), can I set the object size to a % of the actual image size?

Tags: python, google-docs-api

Google Docs V1 API has the `insertInlineImage` endpoint. This endpoint takes the following structure:

```
{
  'insertInlineImage': {
    'location': {
      'index': 1215
    },
    'uri': url,
    'objectSize': {
      'height': {
        'magnitude': 500,
        'unit': 'PT'
      },
      'width': {
        'magnitude': 500,
        'unit': 'PT'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way for me to change the unit type to be a zoom or % factor of the original image size/dimensions instead of using points? I.E. I want the image to be 50% of the size.

**Update:**
Link to the actual docs: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/images#python

Comment: What is `Google Drive API v1's insertInlineImage()`? Can you provide the link of the official document of it?

Comment: Ah yes, check the update in the post.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your updated question, it was found that you wanted to use Google Docs API. In that case, unfortunately, the magnitude of `%` cannot be directly used. So I think that the following flow is required to be done using a script. 1.Retrieve the image size. 2. Calculate the value of `%` from the image size as the value of `magnitude`. 3. Set the calculated value for `magnitude`. If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Right, I read the docs. But in my experience with Google Docs API, the API docs are actually not all that great, hence my question here. I assume when it asks for unit, there are various options for units, otherwise, why make it appear that the units is a parameter you can pass in? That is why I am asking.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I want to find the various options for the unit parameter. One is points or PT. Are there others like Percent?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the current stage, only `PT` can be used at the unit for InsertInlineImageRequest of Google Docs API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#Unit) So I had proposed to use a script. I apologize for this.

Comment: There is only PT as a unit. But you could form a script which takes the original image dimenstions and sets the magnitutde to `size * 0.5` if that's a suitable solution?